# How to scale the image in the Android CollapsingToolbarLayout like WunderList does

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-design-library

Like this two Screenshots below. First imgage is when the toolbar is not collapsed and the second image is the collapsed toolbar. I wonder how to animate & scale the image (T) and fading its title (Tester32)

[image: When not collapse]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[saulmm](https://github.com/saulmm) has recently posted a really nice example of a similar layout ([CoordinatorBehaviorExample](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample)).

You can easily modify it to fit your needs.